# which is the best choice of serving static media files of a website with heavy traffic?

Tags: web-server, website, distributed-filesystems

Take a look at this list http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_systems#Distributed_parallel_fault-tolerant_file_systems

and which is the best choice for storing large number of static media files (with normal file size: 10KB-2M for images, and 5M-500M for video files) of a website? (among these distributed parallel fault tolerant file systems)

Comment: What kind of media files (30Gb high-def mkvs and 3kb GIFs are not equal)?

What kind of traffic (hits per second, unique IPs per second, % cache hits)?

What kind of web server and base OS?

Comment: media files are normal size, images: 10KB-2M, video video files:5M-500M. They are normal media files

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to give a non-answer, but what you're asking raises an eyebrow. If you really need a clustered file system, I would expect some kind of explanation as to why.

**Answer: None of the above** -- go with a "filesystem" that isn't a POSIX compliant file system, but rather a HTTP service oriented towards file storage, replication and redundancy. Examples include [MogileFS](http://danga.com/mogilefs/) (self-hosted, originally created by Brad Fitzpatrick) or Amazon [Simple Storage Service](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) (hosted service), or [Windows Azure's blobs](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/developers/) (.NET, hosted service).

Based on your previous questions you appear to be just starting out, i.e. greenfield development. If so, then generally speaking you're better off purchasing file storage as a service at market price, rather than trying to build something yourself. Getting availability and replication right on a large scale is hard.

Comment: "better  off" is disputable - under constant high load cloud hosting is terribly expensive. It does scale well, though ;)

Comment: @TomTom: I don't disagree, cloud can get very expensive, and the best solution will depend on specific constraints in each case. But a) you're talking about CPU load(?), I'm talking about file storage; and b) in *most* cases I do not think one can build a do-it-yourself solution that will match cloud computing file store reliability and scalability at a similar price point, when all expenses (capital costs, labour costs) are factored in.

Comment: You can, by SIGNIFICANT margins. Heck, even a normal rented server is a lot cheaper. File storage gets really funny if you understand you can get a configured SAN rented for a lot more. All prices USD. Azure: 15 cents / gb / month. For 10.000 gb that is 1500 USD per month storage- bad news, I can build a server handling this for about 6 months rent, EFFICIENTLY, not using large discs. Probably lease cost around 400 USD. Note data goes on top of that. Azure is about 15 cents out.  I pay about 15 USD / mbit. GREAT for spikes etc., but sucks for large significant 24/7 load.

Comment: Every hoster beats the hell out with normal server leases - but then, they don't scale as well and require a lot of commitment.

Comment: @TomTom: It is not an apples-to-apples comparison. I'm not continuing this beyond this comment; we're getting far away from OPs original question.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jesper on this one, personally I'd use a pair of Zeus ZXTM's as coherent caches in front of a pair of standard http servers serving from a single shared NFS/CIFS mount.

That said if you want to do it like this I've had a lot of good experiences with Ibrix myself.

Answer (score -1):

GlusterFS has a very good reputation, but may be overkill for your application. Have you considered distributing the files on server pairs, e.g.

2 ips for static1.yourdomain.com
2 ips for static2.yourdomain.com
...

Always two servers for redundancy. Should any static group get too much traffic, add more servers to that group for scaling.

Comment: -1.... DNS round robin is not high availability (due to DNS caching - basically, a dead server will still get hit). THe idea is sound, the implementation sucks. Rather use static.youdomain.com and use a load balancer (soft or hardware) to route to available hosts.

Comment: That said, static-yourdomain.com is better as it makes sure that cookies are not transmitted even if the programmer forgets about it ;)

Comment: Correct. I only mentioned this method as a simple, "mostly available" alternative because high availability is possibly not a requirement from OP.